# Confused by use of host name in WSDL file in C# Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have created a WCF web service in C# deployed in a Windows Service EXE which is largely working the way I want. I am using it in a self-hosted manner (not within IIS).

In order to make a WSDL file available to the calling Java webservice, I added ServiceMetadataBehavior to the host creation. i.e:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
host.Open();
```

This all worked fine until I moved my service to another server with a different host name. When I connect to the WSDL (http://prod-server:55000/MyService?wsdl), I see that the host name of the development server is hard coded in the WSDL.

Here is a snippet of the WSDL as seen in a browser:

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
<wsdl:import namespace="MyProject.ServiceContracts" location="http://dev-server:55000/MyService?wsdl=wsdl0"/>
<wsdl:types/>
```

I have checked all of the C# code in the project, and the development server name is not hard coded anywhere.

In the App.config file, I have the following defined:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:55000/MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="" contract="MyProject.ServiceContracts.IMyInterface" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55000/MyService" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I would expect that this would result in the localhost machine name being substituted, but it persists as the development box name on which the service was originally created / deployed. Am I mistaken?

I also looked into the possibility of explicitly specifying a path to my WSDL file, but from what I can deduce, this can only be done if hosting the service on IIS.

Lastly and purely out of curiosity, I wonder if an actual WSDL file actually gets created (a physical file on disk I mean) or is it dynamically rendered with each request?

Comment: Note that the host name in the WSDL is only a hint. It is not meant to be the URL of the endpoint, necessarily. It is expected that the client will set the URL of the endpoint that it wishes to communicate with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is created dynamically, not every call IIRC, but on first request to the metadata endpoint. I'm not sure why your seeing your DEV server name on the non-DEV machine, but, because you're specifying localhost only in your endpoint address it's going to resolve DNS using the primary network address for the server. You may want to consider adding the [`useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee816894.aspx) behavior to your config so that the DNS with which the service is accessed is actually used instead.

Answer (score 3):

With WCF the WSDL is dynamically generated.

I have had this problem a number of times on a WCF 3/3.5 service when I needed to send a WSDL to someone as a file.  Typically what I do is save the files (typically there are 3, a wsdl for the service, an xsd for your types, and an xsd for the .net types, but your mileage may vary), then manually update the wsdl imports to reference the other two files relative to the wsdl file, then send all three files.

The `wsdl:service` , `wsdl:port`, and `soap:address` will still reference the dev server, but most ws client libraries account for this and allow the developer to configure the endpoint.

Comment: OK - perhaps I am confused by when the WSDL is actually needed. Is it only referenced at the time the calling code generates the proxy objects, or with every call?

Comment: @Javawanabe: Depends on which Soap library you're using.  Some libraries need the wsdl to generate the client every time the app starts (nusoap for php comes to mind), but some libraries (asmx for example) only need it to generate the client at design time.  If optimum speed and efficiency is your goal, then I would use a library that deciphers the WSDL at design time and then only submits requests/posts to the endpoint at runtime.

Comment: There are options provided by WCF to control this specifically. There's no reason to go with hard WSDL files just to solve this problem.

Comment: @Drew Marsh:  For many SOAP clients having files is a requirement anyway, in my case I work a lot with Tibco BW clients which want to import the schema from files, so that's a perfectly good reason.

Additionally, many of the options to control this, such as `useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress`, are new in .Net 4, and unavailable if you're on an older version.

Comment: @Brook But they could save the files themselves from the URL, right? What am I missing? If you're talking about flattened WSDL files, then just use the WSDL flatting behavior: http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html

Comment: @Drew Marsh: I hadn't seen that URL flattening behavior before, that looks like a good solution.  I guess my answer qualifies as more of a "quick fix" then.